# Logback spring not sending logs to logstash

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, logstash, logback

I have a spring boot app setup to send logs to logstash, which is forwarding logs to elasticsearch. 
My logs seem to not to be getting shipped off however (I am checking the index using elasticsearch's api and none of them come up.

logback-sping.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>

    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}}/spring.log}"/>
    <conversionRule conversionWord="clr" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ColorConverter" />
    <conversionRule conversionWord="wex" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.WhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter" />
    <conversionRule conversionWord="wEx" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ExtendedWhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter" />
    <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" value="${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN:-%clr(%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}}"/>
    <property name="FILE_LOG_PATTERN" value="${FILE_LOG_PATTERN:-%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p} ${PID:- } --- [%t] %-40.40logger{39} : %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}}"/>

    <logger name="org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.WIRE" level="trace"/>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


    <appender name="FILE"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>TRACE</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <cleanHistoryOnStart>${LOG_FILE_CLEAN_HISTORY_ON_START:-false}</cleanHistoryOnStart>
            <fileNamePattern>${ROLLING_FILE_NAME_PATTERN:-${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz}</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>${LOG_FILE_MAX_SIZE:-10MB}</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>${LOG_FILE_MAX_HISTORY:-7}</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>${LOG_FILE_TOTAL_SIZE_CAP:-0}</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <appender name="loggingLogstash" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>TRACE</level>
        </filter>
        <destination>logstash-data.myapp.com</destination>
        <!-- encoder is required -->
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <customFields>{"service_name":"SpringBootLogger"}</customFields>
            <fieldNames>
                <message>log_message</message>
            </fieldNames>
        </encoder>
        <keepAliveDuration>5 minutes</keepAliveDuration>

    </appender>


        <appender name="accessLogstash" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashAccessTcpSocketAppender">
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
                <level>TRACE</level>
            </filter>
            <destination>logstash.myapp.com</destination>
            <!-- encoder is required -->
            <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashAccessEncoder" >
                <customFields>{"service_name":"SpringBootLogger"}</customFields>
                <fieldNames>
                    <message>log_message</message>
                </fieldNames>
            </encoder>
            <keepAliveDuration>5 minutes</keepAliveDuration>
        </appender>



    <root level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="loggingLogstash" />
        <appender-ref ref="accessLogstash" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

i have nginx setup to forward those urls to my logstash docker containers:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name logstash-data.myapp.com;
    keepalive_timeout 70;
    allow all;

    location / {
      proxy_pass     http://logstash:5001;
    }
  }

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name logstash.myapp.com;
    keepalive_timeout 70;
    allow all;

    location / {
      proxy_pass     http://logstash:5000;
    }
  }
```

logstash has these configurations setup:

```
 input {
    tcp {
      port => 5000
      codec => "json_lines"
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    index => "myappjirawebhooklogs"
  }
}
```

and

```
 input {
    tcp {
      port => 5001
      codec => "json_lines"
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    index => "myappjirawebhooklogsdata"
  }
}
```

I switched the logback log level to DEBUG and still saw no particularly meaningful logs. What is wrong with this setup?

I am logging using lombok's @Slf4j log to log inside my classes

Comment: I think that your problem is in your NGINX configuration, your logstash input is tcp, but your nginx reverse proxy is configured ashttp, the tcp reverse proxy configuration is different [according to the documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/#proxy_pass)